# SQL: Trying to select records 7 days before date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a date field called oppo_installdate. This is a date in the future, and I basically want to select records where this date is 7 or fewer days from the current date. I have tried to do this with the query below but it is older returning dates from 2019 as well, and I'm not sure why that's happening.

```sql
select * from [CRM_Test].[dbo].[Opportunity]
where (GETDATE() >= DATEADD(day,-7, oppo_installdate))
```

Could anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you're using a `WHERE` always try to apply any functions to constants, or other functions, never your columns. `DATEADD(day,-7, oppo_installdate)` will make the query non-SARGable, and could slow it down as any indexes won't be able to be used.

It seems like what you simply want is:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Opportunity]
WHERE oppo_installdate >= DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE());
```

Note that `GETDATE` returns a `datetime`, so if you want from midnight 7 days ago, you would use `CONVERT(date,GETDATE())` (or `CAST(GETDATE() AS date)`).

Answer (score 0):

Use below condition-

```
select * from [CRM_Test].[dbo].[Opportunity]
where oppo_installdate>= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) and oppo_installdate<=getdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the records where `oppo_installdate` is 7 or fewer days away from now:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Opportunity]
WHERE oppo_installdate <= DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE())
and oppo_installdate > getdate();
```